# Problem arranging results format from exported registry information

Tags: batch-file

I exported an installed program list from my PC registry as a text file, using a batch script.

```
@echo off
echo ==================

reg export HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall temp1.txt
findstr /L /C:"DisplayName" /C:"DisplayVersion" temp1.txt >> temp3.txt
for /f "tokens=2,3 delims==" %%i in (temp3.txt) do (echo %%i)
```

However I cannot re-arrange those results into a name and version format.

Comment: Please don't SHOUT at us, it's rude. Or check your keyboard to make sure the caps-lock key isn't activated.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Your question *could* be legit, but it lacks some details. BTW: what **is** your question? ("how do I ...", "why...?") Please take some time to read this [ask] and also some of this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking . Else your question will get closed.

Comment: What do you want to get? Something like `DisplayName, DisplayVersion` (`VLC media player, 3.0.12`)?

Answer (score 0):

This is similar to how I'd do it from a [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file), but just for the single specific registry key in your question, *(I'd ask PowerShell to do it)!*

```sh
@Set "KP=SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall"
@Set /A W=90,H=120
@PowerShell -NoP "&{$H=Get-Host;$R=$H.UI.RawUI;$B=$R.BufferSize;"^
 "$W=$R.WindowSize;$B.Width=If (%W% -GT $W.Width) {%W%} Else {$W.Width};"^
 "$B.Height=If (%H% -GT $W.Height) {%H%} Else {$W.height};$R.BufferSize=$B};"^
 "GP 'HKLM:\%KP%\*' -EA SilentlyContinue|? {$_.DisplayName -NE $Null} |"^
 "Select DisplayName,DisplayVersion|FT -A -H"
@Pause
```

*Please note, that your registry key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall` is not the only location you will find installed software, they may also be found under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall`, `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall`, and `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall` too.*

Answer (score 0):

pure batch solution (not so nice output for human eyes, but great for `csv` and much faster (because not loading PowerShell) (same notes as in Compo's answer apply):

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
reg export HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall temp1.txt
for /f "tokens=1,* delims==" %%a in ('type temp1.txt^|findstr /L /C:"DisplayVersion" /c:"DisplayName"') do (
  if "%%~a" == "DisplayName"  set "name=%%~b"
  if "%%~a" == "DisplayVersion" echo !name!, %%~b
)
```

`reg export` writes UTF16, so instead of `findstr ... temp1.txt`, I used `type temp1.txt | findstr ...` to properly process the file.